# DataDog DynamoDB metrics

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, datadog

According to this document https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/amazon_dynamodb/ we should be seeing

> aws.dynamodb.throttled_requests, aws.dynamodb.throttled_requests,
> aws.dynamodb.read_throttle_events, aws.dynamodb.write_throttle_events

But we don't see it in Datadog Metrics/Monitoring. I read through the doc and don't see any specific configuration that needs to be enabled.

Answer (score 2):

i know this is 5 months old, but for others, the Datadog agent i spoke to says this is due to the fact that you cannot use metrics that DD haven't received values for. So - you don't appear to be able to use metrics like this "ahead of time".

I'm going to write a quick script to max out my provisioned throughput and try again after that.

You can see metrics available using the metrics / summary view filtered by Dynamodb